# boost python how to import py in imported python file

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

in my main.cpp:

```
    bp::object main     = bp::import("__main__");
    bp::object globals  = main.attr("__dict__");
    bp::object module   = import("strategy", "strategy.py", globals);
    bp::object Strategy = module.attr("Strategy");
    bp::object strategy = Strategy();
```

but i want to import some self defined py files, in strategy.py I have:

```
from model import Model
```

when i run ./main, it gives error:

```
File "strategy.py", line 2, in <module>
from model import Model
ImportError: No module named model
```

When I test strategy.py without boost python the import works well, how can I fix it?

Comment: Perhaps you need to add the location of those .py files to `sys.path`?

Comment: i am thinking about the same thing, the problem is, if i copy these files to some other PCs, they will have to manually copy them to sys.path as well

Comment: I had some kind of automagic solution in mind. Can you elaborate on how you intend to have this laid out? There's obviously some binary, the strategy.py script and then those dependencies? | For example, in one of my apps that embeds python, I pass the root scripts directory, and the main script name in configuration, and then run something like [this](https://pastebin.com/5Y85yd0J) before importing the main script using a simple `bp::import(name.c_str())` (which itself imports a number of dependencies located in the script directory).

Comment: The thing is the command line interpreter (python.exe) will automatically add either the path of the script it was started with, or an empty string (causing to search in current dir) when running interactive. When you embed, AFAICT it is your responsibility to set it up appropriately.

Comment: I see, thanks Dan, I now know how to fix it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to Dan, I end up with something like this to automatically copy current directory into system path:

```
bp::object sys_module = bp::import("sys"); 
bp::str module_directory = getDir().c_str();
sys_module.attr("path").attr("insert")(1, module_directory);
```

getDir() function:

```
std::string getDir() // get current directory path
{
    char cCurrentPath[FILENAME_MAX];
    if (!GetCurrentDir(cCurrentPath, sizeof(cCurrentPath))){
        return "";
    }
    cCurrentPath[sizeof(cCurrentPath) - 1] = '\0'; 

    return std::string(cCurrentPath);
}
```